# How do I give values[1] the value 0 to avoid getting NaN as result in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to create a program that adds 6 input values between them, but If i don't give a value (for example, if I give only 5 values) the result is NaN. So
I tried to give the empty values the value of 0 using a for loop and an if statement, but It's not working.
May I have your help please?

Code:

```js
document.getElementById("b").onclick = function() {

  var values = new Array();
  values[0] = document.getElementById("x").value;
  values[1] = document.getElementById("y").value;
  values[2] = document.getElementById("z").value;
  values[3] = document.getElementById("a").value;
  values[4] = document.getElementById("g").value;
  values[5] = document.getElementById("c").value;

  for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (isNaN(values[i])) {
      values[i] = 0;
    }
  }

  var risultato = parseFloat(values[0]) + parseFloat(values[1]) + parseFloat(values[2]) + parseFloat(values[3]) + parseFloat(values[4]) + parseFloat(values[5]);

  document.getElementById("risultato").innerHTML = "La massa del prodotto è " + risultato + ".";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 1" id="x" required>

  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 2" id="y" required>

  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 3 (se presente)" id="z">

  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 4 (se presente)" id="a">

  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 5 (se presente)" id="g">

  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 6 (se presente)" id="c">

  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="b" value="Applica" />
</form>

<div id="risultato" class="desc"></div>
```

Edit: This is not a duplicate because the question that I wrote here ([Why can't I do addition between 4 variables in JavaScript but I can do it with 3 variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948215/why-cant-i-do-addition-between-4-variables-in-javascript-but-i-can-do-it-with-3))  is about the addition, and this one is about the isNaN value.

Comment: [Consider using `[]` instead of `new Array()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1273936/3689450)

Comment: `+document.getElementById("x").value` is enough...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I do addition between 4 variables in JavaScript but I can do it with 3 variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948215/why-cant-i-do-addition-between-4-variables-in-javascript-but-i-can-do-it-with-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isNaN` on an empty string return false as an empty string is interpreted as zero (which is a number). Call `parseFloat` on your value before you check for NaN. `parseFloat` returns `NaN` for empty strings. Another option would be to simply check if the string is empty.

i.e. `if (isNaN(parseFloat(values[i]))` or `(values[i].length === 0)`

e.g.

```js
document.getElementById("b").onclick = function() {

  var values = new Array();
  values[0] = document.getElementById("x").value;
  values[1] = document.getElementById("y").value;
  values[2] = document.getElementById("z").value;
  values[3] = document.getElementById("a").value;
  values[4] = document.getElementById("g").value;
  values[5] = document.getElementById("c").value;

  for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (isNaN(parseFloat(values[i]))) {
      values[i] = 0;
    }
  }

  var risultato = parseFloat(values[0]) + parseFloat(values[1]) + parseFloat(values[2]) + parseFloat(values[3]) + parseFloat(values[4]) + parseFloat(values[5]);

  document.getElementById("risultato").innerHTML = "La massa del prodotto è " + risultato + ".";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 1" id="x" required>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 2" id="y" required>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 3 (se presente)" id="z">
  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 4 (se presente)" id="a">
  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 5 (se presente)" id="g">
  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 6 (se presente)" id="c">
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="b" value="Applica" />
</form>

<div id="risultato" class="desc"></div>
```

A simpler way of doing what you want would be something like this. `(parseFloat(a) || 0)` means if `a` isNaN it will be replaced with `0`.

```js
document.getElementById("b").onclick = function() {

  var values = [
    document.getElementById("x").value,
    document.getElementById("y").value,
    document.getElementById("z").value,
    document.getElementById("a").value,
    document.getElementById("g").value,
    document.getElementById("c").value
  ];

  var risultato = values.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return (parseFloat(a) || 0) + (parseFloat(b) || 0);
  }, 0);

  document.getElementById("risultato").innerHTML = "La massa del prodotto è " + risultato + ".";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 1" id="x" required>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 2" id="y" required>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 3 (se presente)" id="z">
  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 4 (se presente)" id="a">
  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 5 (se presente)" id="g">
  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 6 (se presente)" id="c">
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="b" value="Applica" />
</form>

<div id="risultato" class="desc"></div>
```

Comment: Could you explain the first part more easily please?

Answer (score 1):

Add a class name for each input. Get all `inputs` using [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Iterate the `inputs` array. Convert each value to a string using the `+` sign, and add a fallback `|| 0` to 0 if the result is `NaN`. Collect them all in the `sum` variable.

```js
document.getElementById("b").onclick = function() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.number'); // get all elements with the .number class
  var sum = 0; // init sum

  for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    sum += +inputs[i].value || 0; // convert each value to a number, if it's isNaN subtitute 0
  }

  document.getElementById("risultato").innerHTML = "La massa del prodotto è " + sum + ".";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 1" class="number" required>

  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 2" class="number" required>

  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 3 (se presente)" class="number">

  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 4 (se presente)" class="number">

  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 5 (se presente)" class="number"">

  <input type="number" placeholder="Valore 6 (se presente)" class="number">

  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="b" value="Applica" />
</form>

<div id="risultato" class="desc"></div>
```